# Is there a way to avoid using multiple BindingSources?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm experimenting with Entity Framework and right now I have a form where I display results from 3 tables, following is the result:

[image]

to achieve this I had to use 3 BindingSource Objects
[image]

Below is the code but I haven't actually written it, I simply did everything on the designer. just wanted to type the code to show the equivalent of what I did.

```
CONTACTS_BASEBindingSource.DataSource = CONTACTS_BASE;
ORDERSBindingSource.DataSource = CONTACTS_BASEBindingSource
ORDERSBindingSource.DataMember = "ORDERS"
ORDER_TYPESBindingSource.DataSource = ORDERSBindingSource
ORDER_TYPESBindingSource.DataMember = "ORDER_TYPES"
```

by the way, this is how I filled the CONTACTS_BASEBindingSource

```
Context.CONTACTS_BASE.ToList();
```

is there a way to achieve this with fewer BindingSources?

Thanks.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: My Question is: If this can be done using only one binding source